# how to sum values by unique condition on MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns one for date and one for value. the date columns have different dates with duplicates date and the values are different with duplicates values. Is there any way to sum just one value of duplicate dates with just one value of other duplicate dates?
[image]
I tried sumif, sumifs, countif, countifs functions...

Comment: If you are in Excel for Microsoft 365 or Excel 2021, you can play with function UNIQUE. Unfortunately older Excel versions do not support dynamic array formulas, so the UNIQUE function seems to not be available in these versions.

Comment: @AliAshrat what i try is - create a drop down with the words duplicate and unique and based on that i use this formula
      
=IF(H1="Duplicate",SUM(IF(COUNTIF(C2:C7,C2:C7)>1,B2:B7)),SUM(IF(COUNTIF(C2:C7,C2:C7)=1,B2:B7)))
Here on the C column i have the dates and on the B column i have the numbers and in one cell based on what i have selected on the drop down it bring only one value for duplicates and one value for unique values.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In Office 365:
`=SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(C6:D13),,1))`
Which takes the unique rows in the range and takes the first column in the sum.

In older versions:
`=SUMPRODUCT((C6:C13/(COUNTIF(D6:D13,D6:D13))))`

Where it sums all values but divided by the count of the dates occurring in the range. So if it occurs 3 times it sums 3*500/3 =500

For older Excel this may be calculating faster than the above:
`=SUMPRODUCT(C6:C14*(FREQUENCY(D6:D13,D6:D13)>0))`

Note that the first range is expanded one row, since frequency results in an array followed by a `0`